# Custom jquery plugin: '$.myPlugin()' is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello there I know this has been anwsered many times before, but none of the anwsers help me

am trying to load a jquery plugin to bypass cors during development

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.get('https://google.com', function(r) {
        console.log(r);
      });
    });
  </script>


  <script>
    (function($) {
      $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
          if (options.crossDomain) {
            options.url = "https://corsproxy.io/?" + options.url;
          }
        });
        return this;
      };
    }(jQuery));
  </script>
  <script>
    $.myPlugin();
  </script>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

but chrome is always throwing that the plugin is not a function

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.myPlugin is not a function
```

I am realy not sure what I am doing wrong here because it seams that the plugin is properly defined?

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the plugin as `$.fn.myPlugin()`, so it needs to be instantiated on a jQuery object, eg. `$('#foo').myPlugin()`.

However as your intended usage is against `jQuery` itself, therefore you don't need to use `fn` - `$.myPlugin = function() ...`

As a side note, your plugin relies on you setting `crossDomain: true` in the AJAX options, which your original example omitted. This setting will need to be reverted back to `false` for it to not interfere with the request itself.

```js
(function($) {
  $.myPlugin = function() {
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
      if (options.crossDomain) {
        options.url = "https://corsproxy.io/?" + options.url;
        options.crossDomain = false;
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

$.myPlugin();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'https://google.com',
    success: function(r) {
      console.log(r);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe noone mentioned this before :)

Comment: How would settings crossDomain: true interfere with the request itself?

Comment: *I can't believe no-one mentioned this before* - not sure what you mean by this as this answer was pretty quick after you asked.   The reason you won't find this on "how to create a jquery plugin" type tutorials (such as [jquery plugin creation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)) is because you haven't actually created a *plugin*, you've added a method to `$`

Comment: @LimetaPeta it's because using `crossDomain: true` is an outdated way of telling jQuery that you expect the response to be in JSONP format, which won't be the case when you're proxying the request.